# How to characterize conditional entropy given uniform distributions

Tags: probability, information-theory

I'm trying to derive conclusions on how uniform distributions with different alphabet lengths influence the information measured from any other random variable (not neccesarily uniformly distributed). Overall we measure the reduction in the uncertainty of the RV $X$ given $Y$ is observed by means of:
$$H(X|Y) = H(X,Y)-H(Y).$$
Now suppose two random variables $Y$ and $Z$ are uniformly distributed, with $|\mathcal{Y}|<|\mathcal{Z}|$ (and with $|\mathcal{Y}|$ and $|\mathcal{Z}|$ the alphabet sizes). So what is the relationship between  $H(X|Y)$ and $H(X|Z)$?

I initially supposed that given $H(Y)=\log|\mathcal{Y}|<\log|\mathcal{Z}|=H(Z)$ then $H(X|Y) > H(X|Z)$, but I cannot figure out how actually this relationship is influenced by $H(X,\cdot)$ as $|\mathcal{Y}|<|\mathcal{Z}|$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without further specifying any condition on the joint distribution with $X$, it'll be difficult to derive the type of general relationship you're looking for.

Take for example the case when $X = Y$ and $X$ is independent of $Z$.  Then $H(X|Y) = 0 < H(X|Z) = H(X)$.  Alternatively, we can take $X = Z$ and $X$ independent of $Y$ to get the inequality in the other direction